# MATLAB: Why my Pixel Indices are so different from that in Spatial Coordinates

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision

The question is revised to make it more specific and constructive.

I am doing imtransform, yet the xdata and ydata are very much different from that of size(output).

[ output, xdata, ydata ] = imtransform( imgDouble{1}, tform );

Real data test:

```
K>> size(output)

ans =

         854        1230

K>> xdata(2) - xdata(1)

ans =

   1.6635e+03

K>> ydata(2) - ydata(1)

ans =

  876.1373
```

Comment: This seems like MATLAB code. If pasting code, then it would be very useful if you code describe what kind of code are we reading.

Comment: `tform` might be scaling the image to fit the grid, can you post a before and after image.

Answer (score 1):

It is about [Expressing Image Locations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html#brcu_cr).

There are two kinds of image location expression,

One and the most common one is the

pixel indices:

in row and column

The other one is Intrinsic Coordinate System:

express in x and y:

[image]